# d3 - SVG's documentElement turns null after appending to HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

In my project, I have an HTML slider that selects a year and has an EventListener such that when the slider is changed, an SVG corresponding to the selected year is added to a container `div`.

Here's the function called by the EventListener:

```
function loadMap(e) {
    var year = e.target.value;
    container.html(""); //clear previous svg
    container.node().append(svgs[year - 1956].documentElement);
}
```

`svgs` is an array of documents loaded from `d3.xml()`, and `container` holds the `div` as returned by a `d3.select()` for the `div`'s id.

The function loads the content without problem the first time a year is selected. But if I return to that year a second time, `svgs[year - 1956].documentElement` is null. I've tried appending a `documentElement.cloneNode()` instead, and while that fixes the null issue, the SVG graphics aren't showing up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share a working example on codepen/jsfiddle to allow people to help you more easily.